# HTML & CSS - Table attribute in CSS is behaving usual. Don't know how to fix it

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a webpage and decided to tables in CSS to create my navigation bar; all is fine until I go to the cell with email address. The cell sort of skips a column. My webpage code is below, please help.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="action.js"></script>
        <title>Danny Wong: Portfolio</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="cycleImage('latestImage');">
        <div id="header">                               
            <div id="navTableContainer">
                <div class="navTableRow">
                    <div class="navContent">
                        <p class="paraLogo">Danny Wong Art</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="navTableRow">
                    <div class="navContent">
                        Architectural Visualisation
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="navTableRow">
                    <div class="navContent">
                        Envirnoment
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="navTableRow">
                    <div class="navContent">
                        <a href="design.html">Design</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="navTableRow">
                    <div class="navContent">
                        <a href="character.html">Character</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="navTableRow">
                    <div class="navContent">
                        Digital Painting
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="navTableRow">
                    <div class="navContent">
                        Development
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="navTableRow">
                    <div class="navContent">
                        Resume
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="navTableRow">
                    <div class="navContent">
                        <a href="http://dintheart.tumblr.com/">Blog<a/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="navTableRow">       
                    <div class="navContent">                                        
                        <a href="mailto:dwong219@gmail.com">test219@gmail.com</a>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div id="main">         
            <img id="latestImage" src="" alt="image cycler" width="1000" height="600">
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            &copy; 2014 Danny Wong
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Freckle+Face);

body {
    background-color:       #000000;
    color:                  #FFFFFF;
}

#header {
    float:                  left;

    background-color:       tranparent;

    width:                  auto;
    height:                 auto;

    margin:                 0 0 0 0;
    padding:                0 0 0 0;

    border-width:           2px;
    border:                 solid;
}

p.paraLogo {
    font-family:            "freckle face", serif;
    font-size:              36px;
    font-style:             bold;
}

#navTableContainer {
    display:                table;

    background-color:       tranparent;

    width:                  auto;
    height:                 auto;

    margin:                 0 0 0 0;
    padding:                0 0 0 0;

    border-width:           2px;
    border:                 dotted;
}

#navTableContainer a:hover {
    color:                  red;
}

div.navTableRow {
    display:                table-row;

    width:                  auto;
    height:                 auto;

    margin:                 0 0 0 0;
    padding:                0 0 0 0;
}

div.navContent {
    display:                table-cell;

    background-color:       transparent;

    width:                  auto;
    height:                 auto;

    margin:                 0 0 0 0;
    padding:                0 0 0 0;

    border:                 solid;
    border-width:           2px;

    text-align:             center;
    vertical-align:         middle;
}

#main {
    background-color:       transparent;

    width:                  1000px;
    height:                 600px;

    margin:                 -1% auto 0 auto;
    padding:                0 0 0 0;

    border-width:           0;
}

#footer {
    background-color:       transparent;

    width:                  200px;
    margin:                 0 auto 0 auto;

    border-width:           0;
}

a:visited {
    color:                  #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:        none;
}

a:link {
    color:                  #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:        underline;
}
```

Its really getting on my nerves, I know there are other better way and will probably use them, but I really want to find out why this is happening and it could be fixed - for future reference.

Comment: “Skips a column” is a hypothesis of a cause. Please describe the *problem* in directly observable terms. What do you expect to happen, which code do you use for that, and how the results differ from the expectations?

Comment: Can you put this into a jsfiddle

Comment: here is the fiddle of above qus..
http://jsfiddle.net/avinafh/ht5zH/

Comment: as far i can see that problem is with a href as if i will put any other then ok bt as i will use <a href> then it will go left..did you done anything with href?

Comment: You have way to much markup. You could probably achieve what you are after with a well styled `ul`. Still not exactly sure what you are after

Comment: @ jon..he is saying that if i will use all menu..they are in one side then why email section goes on other side when dat also has same css..check my fiddle to know more

Comment: @Leo, your fiddle has an error `<a href="http://dintheart.tumblr.com/">Blog<a/>` (note `<a\>`) in the op code the closing a tag is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li class="paraLogo">Danny Wong Art</li>
        <li>Architectural Visualisation</li>
        <li>Envirnoment</li>
        <li><a href="design.html">Design</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="character.html">Character</a>
        </li>
        <li>Digital Painting</li>
        <li>Development</li>
        <li>Resume</li>
        <li><a href="http://dintheart.tumblr.com/">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="mailto:dwong219@gmail.com">test219zgmail.com</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <img id="latestImage" src="" alt="image cycler" width="1000" height="600" />
</div>
<div id="footer">&copy; 2014 Danny Wong</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Freckle+Face);
 body {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#header {
    float: left;
    background-color: tranparent;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    border-width: 2px;
    border: solid;
}
#header li.paraLogo {
    font-family:"freckle face", serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-style: bold;
    padding: 1em 0;
}
#header ul {
    background-color: tranparent;
    list-style:none;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    border-width: 2px;
    border: dotted;
}
#header ul a:hover {
    color: red;
}
#header li {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#main {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: -1% auto 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    border-width: 0;
}
#footer {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    border-width: 0;
}
a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:link {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ht5zH/2/

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer will not be a big help for you, and maybe I don't understand all your needs,  but I highly reccommend you to design your menu another way than with `display: table;`. An UL list will be easier for the HTML and CSS code.